# Programmatically add FrameworkElement to Page

Tags: c#, xaml

In my UWP app I want to create a `Page` object that I can print. Currently all I have is a list of `FrameworkElement` (WebViewBrush). Is there some way I can make a Page, whose only feature is a FrameworkElement?

I'm thinking something like:

```
Page newPage = new Page();
newPage.Add(frameworkElement);
```

That doesn't work, but that's the sort of thing I'm looking for. I can't *see* anything on https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227503 which demonstrates this but I might be looking for the wrong thing... any advice appreciated, thank you.

#### EDIT

[image]

#### EDIT 2

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Page` can only contain a single child. If you only want a single `FrameworkElement` displayed in the `Page` then you can do:

```
newPage.Content = frameworkElement;
```

Otherwise you will need to create a container that can contain multiple children:

```
StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();

panel.Children.Add(frameworkElement);
// Add your many other children.

newPage.Content = panel;
```

There are of course many other [types of container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb514628(v=vs.90).aspx) that you can use.

**Update**

Just to summarise the eventual solution. Although it might not be ideal it was settled on generating a second `pageList` due to the fact that cloning through `VisualBrush` is not an option in UWP. In theory the brushes should not be large and shouldn't take up too much memory.

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted this as an answer because it broadly works - however when I use your second method I get an error `{"No installed components were detected.\r\n\r\nElement is already the child of another element."}` on the `Children.Add` line? The FrameworkElement is of type `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle` if that helps. Thanks

Comment: To stop seeing that Exception you need to make sure that your frameworkElement is not already added to the UI. Do you still have this line? newPage.Content = frameworkElement; If so remove it and you won't see the exception.

Comment: @b85411 that or you are adding the `frameworkElement` to the `StackPanel` more than once.

Comment: I edited the first message to include a screenshot - I don't think I'm adding it twice. I added a break in the `foreach` to verify that it was occurring the first time it was hit too. Does that code reveal any potential problems? Thanks

Comment: @b85411 the fact that you showing a print mode makes me believe that the `individualPage` is in fact a child of another control. Can you place a breakpoint on the line: `panel.Children.Add(individualPage);` and check what the Parent property on `individualPage` is set to? If it is already displayed somewhere in your application (i.e. Parent is not null) then it will need to be removed from that part of the UI first

Comment: thanks for your reply. I've added another screenshot of the property you requested in my first message. Parent is `null`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121512/discussion-between-bijington-and-b85411).

Comment: I added a follow up query in chat about the "Element is already the child of another element." error - if you have 10 mins free would you mind taking a look? Thank you